# How to get statistic info in Hadoop within the code?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to get some information such as Map input bytes, reduce shuffle bytes, etc within my Java code. This information are printed to console after the Hadoop job is done, however I'm looking for a way to get them in my code?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for Hadoop counters.  Check out http://lintool.github.io/Cloud9/docs/content/counters.html or [Is there a way to access number of successful map tasks from a reduce task in an MR job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009802/is-there-a-way-to-access-number-of-successful-map-tasks-from-a-reduce-task-in-an/8013573#8013573).